# Start an activity. Non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context

Tags: android, gridview, static-methods

I'm trying to make an android app using gridview(http://www.rogcg.com/blog/2013/11/01/gridview-with-auto-resized-images-on-android) and mediaplayer(http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/android-mediaplayer-example/) trying to combine the two tutorials I found so it would be possible to select an image from GridView acitivity launching a MediaPlayer activity that would play a song.

GridView tutorial suggested this to enable the clicking:

```
    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
    {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id)
        {
            // this 'mActivity' parameter is Activity object, you can send the current activity.
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AndroidMediaPlayer.class);
            MainActivity.startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

But I could not get it to work out and got warning:

```
Non-static method 'startActivity(android.content.Intent)' cannot be referenced from a static context
```

Comment: Guys, when you are write unswear look carefully to the questions!
He try call intent in class which don't have any info about context !
startActivity(i) - thats wrong

Comment: From the example He has taken code grid view is defined in activity class so we can use startActivity(i) alone , no need of any context there

Comment: Thank you. I tried `startActivity(i);` it worked also.

Comment: so why down vote for all answers

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
v.getContext().startActivity(i);
```

Get context from your view before calling startActivity or use global context
According to your tutorial you adapter class placed in MainActivity.class
Thats why you also can use next type of calling

```
MainActivity.this.startActivity(i);
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried `startActivity(i);` it worked also.

Answer (score 0):

**Why you are using**  `MainActivity.startActivity(i)`;

Please use `startActivity(i)` insted.

Answer (score -1):

Remove `MainActivity` just use `startActivity(i)`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Hi @TryTryAgain Look at the comment by @Joe . He is telling that `startActivity(i);` worked for him.